# Unsubscribe Firebase cloud messaging client via REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to unsubscribe mobile client via REST API?
I need it so my application server can unsubscribe clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use batchRemove to remove multiple registration tokens from a topic, for more information see: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances

Comment: Is there anyway to unsubscribe only one instance without using batchRemove ? Same way as subscribing with https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME...

Comment: You can send `DELETE` request instead of `POST` request for deleting individual topic from device token.
The requests URL remains the same `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME`